# How to pass a state className variable to another component in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things but i want to pass one class name variable to another component in react.

This is a button which launch an animation onClick just adding one className to few elements of it. Also i created the var = overlay this.state.cliked ? 'open' : '' to launch an overlay, if i have the overlay html on the same component it works fine but i have to do little components as i can.

```
var React = require('react');
var OverlayView = require('./OverlayView.jsx');

var StatusBarButtonView = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {cliked: false};
    },
    handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({cliked: !this.state.cliked});
    },
    render: function() {
    var fondo = this.state.cliked ? 'active' : '';
    var overlay = this.state.cliked ? 'open' : '';

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"statusbar-button-container " + (fondo)} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <img src="images/navbar-element-icon-cross.png" className={"rotate " + (fondo)}/>
                </div>      
            </div>
            <OverlayView className={overlay} />
        );
    }
});

module.exports = StatusBarButtonView;
```

As you see the  is the component of the overlay i want to pass to this component but im not sure if it can just be alone and be launched when this one handle the click. im a bit lost with react, not so much online info and im new with this.

This is the Overlay component:

```
var React = require('react');

var OverlayView = React.createClass({

        return (    
            <div className={"overlay overlay-slidedown " + this.props.class}>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = OverlayView;
```

I'm not sure how to do this, im looking for examples around the web but nothing very clear for me :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Passing class names as strings between components and even appending class names in the same component is error-prone and not ideal. I'd suggest using the classSet() helper: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html

In your case, instead of passing a class prop to the OverlayView component, you should ideally pass a prop that describes the state of the component. Within the OverlayView component, compute the correct classes to be applied using the classSet helper.

For example, instead of using this:
`<OverlayView className={overlay} />`
you could simply pass in the state variable:
`<OverlayView isOpen={this.state.cliked} />`

In your OverlayView component, you would then create a classes object using the className helper:

```
var classes = cx({
   'overlay': true,
   'overlay-slidedown': true,
   'open': this.props.isOpen
});
```

And change the line in your render() function to use the classes object:

```
...
<div className={classes}>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that i dont understand the example of classSet of react tutorial because it looks incomplete, i see the classes but i dont see how that classes are applied. I need a working example or something more clear to understand it. Can you give an example??

Comment: Updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: You are right, at the moment i did the classSet (classnames) to do the class toggle and it works fine. Now i have to try the pass the state prop to the overlay.

Comment: Works perfectly and i learned out how to do more stuff with react, This is awesome!! thank you very much @subeeshb

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 63):

Use this:

```
<div className={`statusbar-button-container ${fondo}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

Note: Make difference between ' and ` (known as backticks). This sign on keyboard is just left to 1 and above tab.

Answer (score 9):

I tried this part of your code...

```
    return (    
        <div className={"overlay overlay-slidedown " + this.props.class}>
     );
```

And it seemed to work perfectly for me.  It solved my problem: a prop failing to interpolate when I want to display it next to some static text.

I find this better than the accepted answer, because that solved the problem by parameterizing the extra concat'd values, when this is often not desired and against general encapsulation philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

I find it much neater to place the classes in an array, and then reference that:

```js
const styles = [
    "container",
    "px-4",
    "h-1/3",
    this.props.class
]
return (
    <div className={styles.join(" ")}>
        Hello!
    </div>
)
```